# What happened in this simple recursion code?

Tags: java, recursion

I can't seem to understand why does the following code prints

```
00
1
10
1
```

by how I see it, it should print the permutations of 2 binary digits.

Please, don't fix my code. I want an explanation of why it works the way it is right now.

```
public static String addZ(int n)
{
    String str ="";
    if(n==0)
        return "";
    str += "0" + addZ(n-1)+"\n";
    str += "1" + addZ(n-1);
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Well, without a main() it can't print anything.

Comment: It looks like you're passing `n=2` to this, and printing the output.  The first two lines come from the first `str +=` in your code, and the next two come from the second `str +=`, in the first call to the method.  Why don't you see what happens when you pass `n=1`?  Then you'll notice how you `n=2` gives you the same output twice over, with the extra `0` and `1`.

Comment: I tried with a kind of "pattern substitution": for n=1 we get "0\n1". lets call it x. For n=2 we get "0x\n1x" which is "00\n1\n10\n1". hope it helps...

Answer (score 4):

If this is related to a homework assignment, you should tag it as such.

Your code generates text using a format like `0{prev}\n1{prev}`, where `{prev}` is the result of a recursive call.  Note that this newline becomes a part of the recursive result and thus will "interrupt" the results of other calls.  Let me show you what I mean.

`n == 0` is the base case and is hardcoded to return an empty string (`""`).

`n == 1` is the first case that can recurse.  Since `{prev}` is the empty string, this returns `0\n1`.  This prints as

```
0
1
```

`n == 2` comes next.  `{prev}` is `0\n1`, so this generates `00\n1\n10\n1`.  As you note, this prints as

```
00
1
10
1
```

`n == 3` is the last step I will show.  `{prev}` is `00\n1\n10\n1`, so it generates `000\n1\n10\n1\n100\n1\n10\n1`, which prints as

```
000
1
10
1
100
1
10
1
```

As a visual aid, I will use different braces to wrap the different recursive returns in the printout.  Curly braces wrap the `n == 0` results, square braces the `n == 1` results, and parentheses wrap the `n == 2` results.

```
0(0[0{}
1{}]
1[0{}
1{}])
1(0[0{}
1{}]
1[0{}
1{}])
```

**EDIT**

The OP said that this is not for a homework assignment, so I have changed my answer to provide a sample Java program that will print all numbers from 0 to 2^`bits` - 1.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        String binaryNumbers = buildBinaryNumbersString(4);
        System.out.println(binaryNumbers);
    }

    private static String buildBinaryNumbersString( int bits ) {
        return recursivelyBuildBinaryNumbersString(bits, "");
    }

    private static String recursivelyBuildBinaryNumbersString( int bits, String prefix ) {
        String result;
        if (bits <= 0) {
            result = prefix;
        } else {
            result =
                recursivelyBuildBinaryNumbersString(bits - 1, prefix + "0") +
                "\n" +
                recursivelyBuildBinaryNumbersString(bits - 1, prefix + "1");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

(You might note that I changed my mind about the newline needing to be in the base case.  This results in the return value not having a potentially extraneous trailing newling.)

This code prints

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
```

This code is very similar to yours, but the difference is what makes it work.  Your code can be thought as trying to build all the binary Strings "beneath" a value, then trying to extend those values to include the next higher bit (though the code did not successfully do this).  This code instead is written to be reused in multiple recursive paths by prepending the "number so far" to the next bit's value of either `0` or `1`.  Thus, the call to `recursivelyBuildBinaryNumbersString()` will vary greatly for the same `bits` value depending upon the passed `prefix`.  Consider what is generated for all these `prefix` values when `bits` is always `1`:

```
prefix: result
000: 0000\n0001
001: 0010\n0011
010: 0100\n0101
011: 0110\n0111
100: 1000\n1001
101: 1010\n1011
110: 1100\n1101
111: 1110\n1111
```

See how these eight prefixes and their eight outputs combined generate all sixteen permutations for four bits?

It is worth noting this technique for passing results so far composed down through the recursive calls.  This technique is just as useful as using recursive calls to return results back up the call chain.  It is worth mentioning that this technique is vital for tail recursion.  For languages that support tail recursion (not Java), and where the return value of a function is a recursive call to that same function, one can write recursive functions so that the last operation performed by that function is a [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).  Loosely speaking, this means that the calling function's stack entry is no longer needed because the called function's stack entry is sufficient to generate the return for the calling function.  This allows the calling function's stack entry to be overwritten with the called function's stack entry, eliminating the danger of stack overflow.  I do not know whether every recursive function can be replaced with an equivalent recursive function that uses tail calls, but even so I have found the idea of passing state-in-progress down through the call chain to be very useful.

Comment: thanks for the explanation,no its not a homework assignment you can just spill it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to understand how a recursive function works, it best to consider it like a tree.  For the function:

```
public static String addZ(int n)
{
    String str ="";
    if(n==0)
        return "";
    str += "0" + addZ(n-1)+"\n";
    str += "1" + addZ(n-1);
    return str;
}
```

Right away we can see that the two `str +=` are really just one call to append to the string the following: `"0" + addZ(n-1) + "\n" + "1" + addZ(n-1)`.

Now if we add some logging to Console, we get a tree like this:

```
str += "0" + addZ([n=2] n-1)+"n";
    str += "0" + addZ([n=1] n-1)+"n";
        addZ(n = 0) = ""
    str += "1" + addZ([n=1] n-1);
        addZ(n = 0) = ""
str += "1" + addZ([n=2] n-1);
    str += "0" + addZ([n=1] n-1)+"n";
        addZ(n = 0) = ""
    str += "1" + addZ([n=1] n-1);
        addZ(n = 0) = ""
```

The advantage to this output is you can then just roll it up

```
str += "0" + {addZ([n=2] n-1) = "0" + "" + "\n" + "1" + ""} +"\n";
    str += "0" + {addZ([n=1] n-1) = ""} +"\n";
        addZ(n == 0) = ""
    str += "1" + {addZ([n=1] n-1) = ""};
        addZ(n == 0) = ""
str += "1" + {addZ([n=2] n-1) = "0" + "" + "\n" + "1" + ""};
    str += "0" + {addZ([n=1] n-1) = ""}+"\n";
        addZ(n == 0) = ""
    str += "1" + {addZ([n=1] n-1) = ""};
        addZ(n == 0) = ""
```

Therefore

```
addZ(n = 2) = "0" + {"0" + "" + "\n" + "1" + ""} +"\n" "1" + {"0" + "" + "\n" + "1" + ""}
addZ(n = 2) = "00\n1\n10\n1"
```

Which is your output of:

```
00
1
10
1
```

If you would like to experience with large values of `n`, I would suggest adding logging to your code like such: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MqqnuM

Answer (score 1):

With recursion you are adding function calls to the top of the stack until you reach the base case, then you begin popping calls off the stack.

In the case of `addZ(2)`  str is declared as an empty string and then given the value "0" + the return value of addZ(2-1) or addZ(1).

`addZ(1)`  declares it's own empty str, which is given the value "0" + the return value of addZ(1-1) or addZ(0).

addZ(0) is the base case, returning an empty `String` to `addZ(1)`

`addZ(1)` still only has a str with a value of "0" to which it adds the newline character "\n".

`addZ(1)` then adds the value "1" to str + the return value of addZ(0), which as we know from above is an empty string.

`addZ(1)` returns str to `addZ(2)` with a value of "0\n1"

`addZ(2)` continues by adding a newline character to str.

At this point str = "00\n\1\n", which is what your output sample is showing.

`addZ(2)` then adds "1" + the return value of addZ(2-1) or addZ(1) to str.

From above, we know `addZ(1)` ultimately returns "0\n1"

str now holds the value "00\n\1\n10\n1" and the function is finished.

Basically, just follow the logic.  It may also help to step through it with a debugger if you have a hard time wrapping your head around recursion.